# Absolute file path of assets in Rails' asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, actioncontroller

I can get the absolute path of a resource like so:

```
Rails.root.join("public", ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_url('image.jpg').sub("/",""))

# => #<Pathname:/Users/Benjamin/apps/app1/public/image.jpg>
```

This will work with the asset pipeline (I think) but it doesn't feel like a nice way to do this. Any suggestions on how I could do this better?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
File.expand_path('image.jpg')
```